How to calculate YoY Growth without a Date Field in Pivot?
I have an Excel table in the following format:



Product
Subclass
Year-over-Year (YoY)
Current Year Sales
Previous Year Sales




Apple
1
+50%
30
20


Apple
2
25%
50
40


Apple
3
-10%
76
80



From this I generate a pivot table and consolidate the results on the 'Product' (Apple):



Product
Year-over-Year (YoY)




Apple
???



Solutions like for example here did not provide an answer for my case to correctly calculate the YoY (+11.4%) across the board for all apple products.
Hence: How can I calculate the YoY correctly in my situation in a pivot table?

Assuming you created a Pivot Table without adding the data to the 'data model': use PivotTable Analyze->Fields, Items, & Sets->Calculated Field.
Change the FieldName to 'YOY Growth,
In formula type the expression: =('Current Year Sales'-'Previous Year Sales' )/'Previous Year Sales'
and enter.

You have to define a calculated field in your pivot table:
=('Current Year Sales' -'Previous Year Sales')/'Previous Year Sales'*100



